# Map nested collection in lookup

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have two collections: items and commisions.

```
// collection items
{
    _id: ObjectId("5d2b9e2da676e50cb9d061fe"),
    name: 'some name'
}

// collection commisions
{ 
    _id: ObjectId("5d2cb8ad7240251917b18c03"),
    items: [
        {
          item: ObjectId("5d2b9e2da676e50cb9d061fe")
        }
    ]
}
```

Now using aggregation I need to find items with commision count (in how many commisions they appear). I'm trying with it:

```
db.getCollection('items').aggregate([{
        $match: {
            _id: ObjectId("5d2b9e2da676e50cb9d061fe")
        }
    }, {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'commisions',
            let: {
                item: '$_id',
                items: {
                    $map: {
                        input: '$items',
                        as: 'i',
                        in: '$$i.item',
                    }
                }
            },
            pipeline: [{
                $match: {
                    $expr: {
                        $in: ['$item', '$items']
                    }
                }
            }],
            as: 'commisions'
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            commisions: 1,
            commisionsSize: { $size: '$commisions' }
    }
},
{
    $limit: 100
}
])
```

But when I try to run this query I'm getting:

"errmsg" : "$in requires an array as a second argument, found: missing"

Problem is that `commision.items` is not a flat array but nested.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just got a little confused with your `$lookup` syntax, Specifically the variable you define in the `let` part are suppose to belong to the current collection and not the collection you're about to lookup from.

Try this:

```
 db.getCollection('items').aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            _id: ObjectId("5d2b9e2da676e50cb9d061fe")
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'commisions',
            let: {item: '$_id'},
            pipeline: [
                {
                    $match: {
                        $expr: {
                            $in: [
                                '$$item',
                                {
                                    $map: {
                                        input: '$items',
                                        as: 'i',
                                        in: '$$i.item',
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }],
            as: 'commisions'
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            commisions: 1,
            commisionsSize: {$size: '$commisions'}
        }
    },
    {
        $limit: 100
    }
])
```

Comment: Nice! I think I have messed up with `'$$item'`